# I can only think brute-force solution. How can I perform recursion?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

> There are two integer arrays A and B of equal length. Add elements of A to elements of B so that all elements in B become equal(if possible). One can add i’th element of A to i’th or i+1(if i != len(A)) element of B only, or don't add anything and move on to next element. An element of A can be used only once.

Example :
B = [3,5,4,2], A = [2,1,2,1]

B[0] += A[0]

B[2] += A[1]

B[3] += A[2]+A[3]

So, B becomes [5,5,5,5]

Comment: Looks like a homework for me. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ari0nhh making a 2d array with every possible combination for every element and comparing them then

Comment: Why do you think recursion is what you are looking for?

Comment: @4386427 I did some rough paper work, and it seemed like it could be done with recursion. Although, I'm not sure.

Comment: The problem is not well-defined. What do you mean by "become equal (if possible)"? 1) Maximize the number of equal elements? 2) Minimize the standard deviation of the elements? 3) Something else?

Comment: Your description and your example in the comment differs. According to the description a[1] can be added to the b[1] or b[2]. But in the example you add it to b[0].

Comment: @4386427 sorry. But I hope, you get it.

Comment: I don't - is the description or the example correct. If the rules are unclear it is impossible to come up with any solution

Comment: @4386427 description is correct.

Comment: So the goal is to make `B[0] = B[1] ... = B[3]` using the rule that `B[i]` must be composed of either `b[i]+A[i]` or `b[i]+A[i-1]` or `b[i]+A[i]+A[i-1]`? I'm using `b` = initial `B`.

Comment: @Dev ok :) you should update your question and add something like i've written here so it's clear to all what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider recursion for this problem. A simple `while` is sufficient.

First thing to notice is that b_new[0] can only have two values

```
b_new[0] = b[0];        // and a[0] not used
b_new[0] = b[0] + a[0]; // and a[0] used
```

For b_new[1] that leaves 4 possibilities

```
b_new[1] = b[1];               // and a[1] not used
b_new[1] = b[1] + a[0];        // and a[1] not used, only valid if a[0] wasn't used
b_new[1] = b[1] + a[0] + a[1]; // and a[1] used, only valid if a[0] wasn't used
b_new[1] = b[1] + a[1];        // and a[1] used
```

For these you should always give priority to the two first so that a[1] is free to be used for calculating b[2].

Expressed in a function that would be:

```
int tryit(int idx, int target, int* a, int* b, int previous_a_used)
{
  if (b[idx] == target)
  {
    return 0; // a[idx] is free
  }

  if (!previous_a_used)
  {
    if ((b[idx] + a[idx-1]) == target)
    {
      printf("Trying: b[%d] += a[%d]\n", idx, idx-1);
      return 0; // a[idx] is free
    }

    if ((b[idx] + a[idx-1] + a[idx]) == target)
    {
      printf("Trying: b[%d] += a[%d] + a[%d]\n", idx, idx-1, idx);
      return 1; // a[idx] is used
    }
  }

  if ((b[idx] + a[idx]) == target)
  {
    printf("Trying: b[%d] += a[%d]\n", idx, idx);
    return 1; // a[idx] is used
  }

  return -1; // failed - no solution
}
```

The function can be used like:

```
  printf("Trying: b[%d] += a[%d]\n", 0, 0);

  target = b[0] + a[0];   // Try one of the two possibilities for target
  previous_a_used = 1;    // a[0] was used
  idx = 1;                // move on to next index for b

  while (idx < N)
  {
    previous_a_used = tryit(idx, target, a, b, previous_a_used);
    if (previous_a_used < 0)
    {
      printf("failed\n");
      break;
    }
    ++idx; // move on to next index for b
  }

  if (previous_a_used >= 0)
  {
    printf("Solved\n");
  }
```

Remember to add code for checking the other target value (i.e. `target = b[0]`).